# Calculate the output of volume and surface area of a sphere

Tags: python

The volume and surface area of a sphere can be calculated with the following formulas. Create this as a terminal application. Write one function for volume and another function for surface area. The results should display both the volume and the surface area rounded to 2 decimal places. Use pi from Python’s math module. Include the following doctests. You must get pass
all tests to receive full credit. Pay close attention to how you name your functions. They must
match

volume examples/doctests:

- round(volume_of_sphere(0), 2)

  - 0.0
- round(volume_of_sphere(1), 2)

  - 4.19
- round(volume_of_sphere(12.3), 2)

  - 7794.78
- round(volume_of_sphere(18.9), 2)

  - 28279.65
- round(volume_of_sphere(33.33), 2)

  - 155093.84

surface area examples/doctests:

- round(surface_area(0), 2)

  - 0.0
- round(surface_area(1), 2)

  - 12.57
- round(surface_area(12.3), 2)

  - 1901.17
- round(surface_area(18.9), 2)

  - 13959.84
- round(surface_area(33.33), 2)

  - 155093.84

```
MY CODE:
''' Python3 program to calculate Volume and
Surface area of Sphere'''
# Importing Math library for value Of PI
import math
pi = math.pi

# Function to calculate Volume of Sphere
def volume(r):
    vol = (4 / 3) * pi * r * r * r
    return vol

# Function To Calculate Surface Area of Sphere
def surfacearea(s):
    sur_ar = 4 * pi * r * r
    return sur_ar

# Driver Code
radius = round(volume(1), 2)
area = round(area(0), 2)
print( "Volume Of Sphere : ", volume(radius) )
print( "Surface Area Of Sphere : ", surfacearea(area) )
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The two programs below will find the surface area and the volume of a sphere with the radius. This is just a simpler way. The first program is more accurate but both will do the job.

```
pi=22/7
radian = float(input('Radius of sphere: '))
sur_area = 4 * pi * radian **2
volume = (4/3) * (pi * radian ** 3)
print("Surface Area is: ", sur_area)
print("Volume is: ", volume)
```

or

```
PI = 3.14
radius = float(input('Please Enter the Radius of a Sphere: '))
sa =  4 * PI * radius * radius
Volume = (4 / 3) * PI * radius * radius * radius

print("\n The Surface area of a Sphere = %.2f" %sa)
print("\n The Volume of a Sphere = %.2f" %Volume)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: How and where would I add the round() Functions?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no obvious question here, I am assuming the objective is to complete the mathematical functions and pass the doctests. Having said that, it would be quite impossible to do that without being mathematically incorrect because the last two doctests for the surface area function are wrong, `round(surface_area(18.9), 2)` should be 4488.83 not 13959.84 and `round(surface_area(33.33), 2)` should be 13934.72 and not 155093.84.